# Avoid almost duplicating query in postgres plpgsql function

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql

Is there a better way to write this query in a plpgsql function than almost duplicating the query twice? Any way to say if `valB` is null then it should match anything in `colB`, essentially being removed from the where clause?

```
if (valB is not null) then
    update mytable set colA = valA where (colB, colC) = (valB, valC);
else
    update mytable set colA = valA where (colC) = (valC);
end if;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `OR` condition with the parameter:

```
update mytable 
   set colA = valA 
where (valb is null and colC = valC)
   or (valb is not null and (colb, colc) = (valb, valc));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `or`.  I would phrase this as:

```
update mytable 
   set colA = valA 
where colC = valC and
       (valb is null or colb = valb);
```

Comment: Would you say there's any practical difference between what you suggested and modifying it slightly, replacing `(valb is null or colb = valb)` with `(colb = case when valb is null then colb else valb end)` or are they identical? Does the other way have any downsides in terms of performance or anything else (apart from being a bit longer to read)?

Comment: @user779159 . . . I prefer leaving `case` expressions out of `where` clauses.